# VSCode command palette is showing i18n IDs instead of names, how do I fix this

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to set up a machine running Fedora as my main driver for development in Python. I got the VS Code installed, but when I went on to configure the virtual environments, I noticed the Command Palette is displaying the variables IDs instead of its value, and it doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of the Command Palette]

Both the Python extension and the VSCode were removed, reinstalled, the system was rebooted and nothing seems to work as it should.

I'm currently using a Linux Fedora 38 distribution, and my VSCode was installed through a repository:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[code]\nname=Visual Studio Code\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo'
```

Here is a screenshot of the VSCode version info, after it is installed:

[image]

Both my OS and applications on that Linux machine are all set to en_US.

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VSCode? Do commands from other sources show correctly? Try checking ones from other extensions and builtins.

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure what's causing this. Please [edit] the question to include the troubleshooting you've already done, so other people can see it more easily. And add version info for your OS, VSCode, and the Python extension.

Comment: Please copy and paste the **textual** output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: does this happen for all commands? Or only for commands contributed by specific extensions? If the latter, which extensions? Example of extension bugs: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12333

Comment: It might be an issue with language setting of your OS/login session. It looks to me like the intl package if VS code does not find the translations which is based on your language setting. Check how to set your language locale in Fedora and try en_US.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Does installing a [pre-release](https://imgur.com/7Ahhuoz.png) fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone faces the same issue I had with VSCode and Fedora, I solved the issue by removing the VSCode application, removing the repository from my list of repositories, so it doesn't get installed again by mistake.

Then I downloaded and installed the RPM from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-rpm-x64

Now it is working perfectly.

I still don't have a solution for the repository version of the VSCode, but localinstall of the RPM is working fine.